finding the limit of a function composed with itself
Is it possible to find a function $f$ such that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$ is $0$ but the limit of $f(f(x))$ as $x$ approaches $0$ is something else?

You should supply some more context: what have you tried? What went wrong? As for the mathematics, just systematically apply the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit, to the question "does $f(f(x))$ tend to $0$ as $x$ tends to $0$?".

Let us take
$$
f(x):=
\begin{cases}
0, &x\neq 0\\
1, &x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then obviously
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0,\qquad\lim_{x\to 0}f(f(x))=1.
$$

Please don't answer problem statements. This site has quality standards, see "Enforcement of quality standards

Note that the answer by Pavel R. provides a counterexample, but the $f$ in there has a discontinuity at $0$.
I claim that if $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, then the statement you ask about is true. Can you see why?

Please don't answer problem statements. This site has quality standards, see "Enforcement of quality standards

@amWhy: I agree with those in general, and if you look closely you might see my answer actually puts the ball back into OP's court, thereby, I think, actually enforcing quality standards.
